# Dynamic Supervisor Spec in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor, gen-server

I have created a GameSupervisor supervision module that I use to dynamically create a child of instance GameServer (GenServer). I can see GameServer's start_link method is invoked when GameSupervisor.start function is called but it doesn't keep the pid alive. Process.alive?(pid) in iex always return false if the restart strategy is set to temporary. If I set the restart to transient or permanent it ends up calling GameServer.start_link again when I call GenServer.cast on that pid.

Is invoking start_child not automatically add the pid to the supervision tree and keep it alive?

GameSupervisor.ex

```
defmodule Prest.GameSupervisor do

  alias Prest.GameServer
  use Supervisor

  @name :game_sup

  def start_link() do
    IO.puts "start link"
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [], [name: @name])
  end

  def start(uid) do
    IO.puts "start bucket"
    {:ok, child} = Supervisor.start_child(@name, [uid])
  end

  def init([]) do
    IO.puts "init sup"
    children = [
      worker(GameServer, [], restart: :transient)
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one)
  end

end
```

GameServer.ex

```
  defmodule Prest.GameServer do
  use GenServer

  # Client API

  def start_link(uid) do
    IO.puts "start game server"
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, uid, [])
  end

  def post(pid, event_id) do
    :gen_server.cast(pid, {:event, event_id})
  end

  # Server API

  def init(uid) do
    {:ok, {uid, [], []}}
  end

  def handle_cast({:event, event_id}, state) do
    #state = [event_id|state]
    {:noreply, "ok", state}
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html):

- A `:permanent` process is always restarted, even if it terminates normally.
- A `:transient` process is restarted only if it terminates abnormally.
- A `:temporary` process is never restarted.

More than likely, your `GameServer` process is crashing for one reason or another, and the supervisor is handling restarts the way it's configured to.

To debug this, you'll want to check your logs (which may only be output to the terminal) to see the reason why the process is crashing. If you're able to get an `{:ok, pid}` for it, then it's probably not crashing on init, which means a `handle_cast`, `handle_call`, or `handle_info` clause is responsible for the crash.

<del>Without code, it's hard to offer more specific help.</del>

In this case, it looks like your `handle_cast` has a bad return value. It [should return](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_cast/2) `{:noreply, state}`, but is returning `{:noreply, "ok", state}`. This is often caused by changing a `handle_call` to `handle_cast`, and forgetting to remove the reply value.

Comment: That's pretty simple code - hard to see how any errors would be popping up. Do you have a github link? I'm happy to do some debugging tonight.

Comment: Actually, i do see the error. The `handle_cast` has a bad return value. http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_cast/2

Comment: Specifically, it should return `{:noreply, state}` instead of `{:noreply, "ok", state}`

Comment: That did it. It was handle_call earlier but forgot to change the arguments. Thanks!